# Do I require a transit visa at Frankfurt if travelling to the United Kingdom?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, germany, transit-visas

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/aamt/zugastimaa/buergerservice/faq/33-transit/606710

What I am confused about is they have mentioned the vast majority of foreign travellers benefit from 'transit privilege' which doesn't require a visa, but they have also mentioned some countries do not have 'transit privilege', which also includes India. But even Indians aren't required a transit visa if they are holders of a valid visa from the EEA countries and visas issued by Japan, Canada and the United States of America.

The UK used to be a part of EEA and EU, but its no longer part of it now because Brexit happened, and it is in transition period. So can I use airport transit privilege in Germany without a German airport transit visa if I am travelling to the UK? Do EU and EEA laws still apply during the transition period?

Comment: What is the nationality of your passport? India?

Comment: yes it is Indian

Comment: What is your itinerary?

Comment: The flight I am looking at has 1 stop at Frankfurt International Airport and has a 3h 55m layover there.Please give me advice whether I need it or not.I don't want to travel without transit visa if I need it because it would just be better to cancel the flight then.

Comment: Brexit has nothing to do with this except perhaps to explain why the information you found online seemed contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: you can transfer airside at Frankfurt without a transit visa.

Longer Answer: Airlines check passenger documents carefully before boarding. The IATA database Timatic collects and presents this information to the airline, which is reviewed before a boarding pass is issued.

The German Federal Foreign Office presents different eligibility information in the page cited in your question. The airline, however, will check your eligibility to fly based on the Timatic database, not on the content of a governmental webpage.

Using your information in one of the many Timatic public access portals ([here's one](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) from Olympic Airways), generates the following information.

> National India (IN)             /Transit Germany (DE)
> Destination United Kingdom (GB)
> ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> ...
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India transiting
> through Frankfurt (FRA) or Munich (MUC), arriving from a
> non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a
> flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a
> Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus,
>   Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

The UK is not now an EU member state, having withdrawn January 31, 2020. The UK is also not a member state under the Schengen agreement.

Other requirements appear further down in the Timatic report:

> Warning:
>
> - Passports must be signed by the holder.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a passport that has
>   a fingerprint instead of a signature.
> - This does not apply to passengers with a passport that has
>   a remark stating that a signature is not required or that
>   the holder cannot sign the passport.
> - Further exemptions exist for minors, based on national laws

If you have an Indian passport valid for the duration of your trip signed by you (and not an Indian passport with a fingerprint instead of a signature, or one which recites that a signature is not required), a valid UK visa, and a ticket from FRA to the UK, your 3 hr 55 min layover in FRA qualifies you for this exception.

Thus, you do not need a transit visa for the layover in Germany.